# Accessing a Constant Defined in ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to access the constant `VALID_FIND_OPTIONS` defined in `ActiveRecord::Base` (`active_record/base.rb` Line 2402 Rails 2.3.5).

```
ActiveRecord::Base::VALID_FIND_OPTIONS
```

I get the `NameError` exception.

```
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::VALID_FIND_OPTIONS
```

I have accessed the class constants in other libraries using the similar syntax before. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constant `VALID_FIND_OPTIONS` was defined inside the anonymous class of `ActiveRecord::Base`, hence it was not accessible as `ActiveRecord::Base::VALID_FIND_OPTIONS`

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    class << self
      # the constant belongs to the scope of the anonymous class
      VALID_FIND_OPTIONS = [..]
    end
  end
end
```

The constant can be accessed using following syntax:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class::VALID_FIND_OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 1):

Where is the code that tries to get `ActiveRecord::Base::VALID_FIND_OPTIONS`?

If you are defining a class before ActiveRecord is loaded, then the constant will not be available.

You can force ActiveRecord to be loaded by requiring it. In some cases, you will have to require rubygems before requiring `active_record`.

Try requiring them both:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

# you should now be able to access ActiveRecord::Base::VALID_FIND_OPTIONS
```

Comment: I access the constant in my controller. I get the same error when I use it from rails console (where active_record is loaded by default).